# Why isn't the public IP address contactable

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-vm-role

I just spun up a VM on Azure, then set up IIS with the usual defaults, and the usual default website.

When logged on to the server (2008 R2) with Remote Desktop, I can enter in the public or internal IP address and see the default IIS 7 website.

However, from outside, the website is not contactable.

When I look at the bindings in IIS, it shows the internal address, but not the external IP address.

Is there something else I need to do to make the external IP address work?

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spinning up an VM does not make it public accessable. Your VM is linked to a cloudservice which acts as a loadbalancer (for 1..x VM's).

In the cloudservice you can configure which public ports are available and passed through to your VM's.

So in the cloudservice you have to configure that it will pass port 80 (or 443) to your VM's.

Comment: In case you're searching for other documentation, this is known as configuring your service's endpoints.

Comment: Thank you, I spent quite some time searching for an answer to this.